# include php linking not working [ localhost ] php

Tags: php

I cant seem to make `include` to work in php

i'm trying to define a function in test.php

and i'm trying to link it to another file out side the test.php file directory
what i tried so far is :

```
include ('../functions.php');  // Doesn't work
```

*error message undefined  -- functionname(); in test.php*

```
include ('Doc\somethings\functions.php');  // Doesn't work
```

**What worked for me is putting the whole link to define the functions !
==>**

```
includes ('F:\JF2\993\Doc\somethings\functions.php') // working but not Ideal ]
```

I read some devs have the same issue , they told them use this

```
include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "../../functions.php");

*Or Try to locate the file path using* 

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];  // [ This Shows the root file path and it's not ideal for me ]
```

**Output**

```
F:\JF2\993\Doc\
```

****am i missing something ?****

---

**test.php location**

```
F:\JF2\993\Doc\somethings\scripts\test.php
```

**functions.php location**

```
F:\JF2\993\Doc\somethings\functions.php
```

additional info :-

Php 7.4

( i need to define a function from a file so i dont have to rewrite it again and again )

Comment: Isn't it just `../functions.php`?

Comment: i added the file file in ../functions.php     --    ../../functions.php , it didn't work

Comment: You are including functions.php inside another file
What is the path to functions.php and the path to the file it contained in?

Comment: F:\JF2\993\Doc\somethings\functions.php

Comment: the include function is in  :: F:\JF2\993\Doc\somethings\scripts\test.php   , but the functions commands it's on functions.php

Comment: just use like this ../functions.php

Comment: didn't work for me include(../functions.php);

Comment: bool(false) error message

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but still bool(false)

Comment: AFAIK, the path using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the standard

Answer (score 1):

**Php call and include functions**

```
require_once '../functions.php';

include '../functions.php';

require '../functions.php';

header("Location: ../functions.php");
```

try this

Comment: Thanks but still for somereson includes isn't defining the file outside the directory it's only defining the file that on the same directory path

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simply define a global that is my base path url, from there on out, i run it like this

```
if(defined('BASE_PATH')) {

    if(is_file(BASE_PATH.'/core/db/db-config.php')){
    
        require_once (BASE_PATH.'/core/func/system.php');
    
        require_once (BASE_PATH.'/core/db/db.php');
        
        require_once (BASE_PATH.'/core/func/form.php');

    }

}
```

for the definition of the basepath, i run as first command in my index.php the following

```
if(!defined('BASE_PATH')) {

    define( 'BASE_PATH',  __DIR__);

}
```

I do have a fallback that if the defined path is not made (when i go outside of the system to do for instance ajax calls), i add a variable to the session to actually catch that as well.

Why do i do this? Because i prefer to see the full path, and I have no intention on figuring out how many directories i have to step out in order to find what i am looking for. This is also a way to look at it.